# GLFW issue with std::thread; glfwSwapBuffers(window) not working properly

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl, concurrency, glfw

Function 1 calls Function 2 which calls Function 3

The problem on hand is that the two commented lined of code in function 1 do not run as expected. I have a display which is just black because of these lines.

```
//std::thread *thread1 = new std::thread(&Screen::DisplayRows, this, pbr );
//thread1->join();
```

However, the line underneath those two lines  `DisplayRows(pbr);` seems to work just fine and the display is shown properly. Essentially I am looking for a number of threads to be created in the for loop of Function 1 and for those threads to update the display through  `glfwSwapBuffers(_window);` in Function 3.

Right now, the two commented lines of code do call Function 3 but the display is not updated. The commented lines and the `DisplayRows(pbr);` should do the same thing but the display does not reflect the same when it comes to the commented lines.

Function 1

```
void Screen::Display(Container* PBC, SimpleSorter *Solution)
{
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // Scale to window size
        GLint windowWidth, windowHeight;
        glfwGetWindowSize(window, &windowWidth, &windowHeight);
        glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

        // Draw stuff
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   // Set the background color
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 0, 1);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

    PBC->DrawContainer();// 0, 0);

    std::vector<PixelBlockRow> row = PBC->getRows();

    for ( int i =0; i <PBC->getRows().size(); i ++)
    {
        PixelBlockRow *pbr = &row[i];
        //std::thread *thread1 = new std::thread(&Screen::DisplayRows, this, pbr );
        //thread1->join();
        DisplayRows(pbr);
        }
        getchar();
    }
}
```

Function 2

```
void Screen::DisplayRows(PixelBlockRow *PBR)
{
        _Solution->Sort(PBR);

}
```

Function 3

```
void SimpleSorter::Sort( PixelBlockRow * p)
{
    auto block = p->GetRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < block.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (block[i].GetColor().GetR() < block[j].GetColor().GetR())
            {
                Color c = block[i].GetColor();
                block[i].SetColor(block[j].GetColor());
                block[j].SetColor(c);
                p->DrawPixelBlockRow();
                Sleep(5);
                glfwSwapBuffers(_window);
                std::cout << ij++ << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < block.size(); i++) {
        Color c = block[i].GetColor();
        std::cout << "(" << c.GetR() << "," << c.GetG() << "," << c.GetB() << "),";
    }
}
```

Comment: An OpenGL context is always bound to exactly one thread. If you want to call OpenGL commands from a different thread, you have to rebind the context to that thread.

Comment: I tried adding the line `glfwMakeContextCurrent(_window);` before the line `glfwSwapBuffers(_window);` but it made no difference. Is there something else that I should be doing?

Comment: @BDL: And *unbind* it from the original thread.

Comment: Cheers guys, that worked brilliantly. Thank you so much!